# Match True in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In JavaScript, using the `switch` statement, I can do the following code:

```js
switch(true){
    case 1 === 1:
        console.log(1)
        break

    case 1 > 1:
        console.log(2)
        break

    default:
        console.log(3)
        break
}
```

And it's going to return `1`, since JavaScript `switch` is comparing `true === (1 === 1)`

But the same does not happen when I try it with Python `Match` statement, like as follows:

```py
match True:
    case 1 = 1:
        print(1)

    case 1 > 1:
        print(2)

    case _:
        print(3)
```

It returns:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    case 1 = 1:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And another error is returned if I try it this way:

```py
Check1 = 1 == 1
Check2 = 1 > 1

match True:
    case Check1:
        print(1)

    case Check2:
        print(2)

    case _:
        print(3)
```

It returns:

```
case Check1:
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: name capture 'Check1' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

What would be the **cleanest/fastest** way to do many different checks without using a lot of **if's** and **elif's**?

Comment: This use-case is still best served with an if-elif ladder. Pattern matching using `match` is not meant to be used this way.

Comment: @rdas so there's might be no viable alternative to the if-elif ladder?

Comment: I don't believe you are implementing the match function correctly.  Take a look at [How to Use a match case Statement in Python 3.10](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-match-case-statement/) for suggestions on how to use correctly.

Comment: rdas is right but even if they weren't your statement is trying to assign a value of 1 to the number 1. At the very least it would be `1==1`

Comment: I think it's worth adding that Javascript is *weird* for allowing arbitrary expressions in `case` statements. Normally a `switch` statement is meant to choose between some set of constant values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In JavaScript, using the switch statement, I can do the following code

I definitely wouldn't be using JavaScript as any form of litmus or comparator for python.

---

If you used `1==1` in your first test case, the below is what both of your test cases are ultimately doing.

```
match True:
    case True:
        print(1)

    case False: #will never get hit
        print(2)

    case _:     #will never get hit
        print(3)
```

This is why you get the error for the second version. `True` will only ever be `True`, so no other case will ever be hit.

Based on your example, it seems like you are trying to use `match/case` just to determine the "truthiness" of an expression. Put the expression in the `match`.

```
match a==1:
    case True: 
        pass
    case False:
        pass
```

If you have a lot of expressions, you could do something like the below, although I don't think this is very good.

```
a = 2

match (a==1, a>1):
    case (True, False):
        print('equals 1')
    case (False, True):
        print('greater than 1')
    case _:
        print(_)

#OR

match ((a>1) << 1) | (a==1):
    case 1:
        print('equals 1')
    case 2:
        print('greater than 1')
    case _:
        print(_)
```

`cases` should be possible results of the `match`, NOT expressions that attempt to emulate the `match`. You're doing it backwards. The below link should tell you pretty much everything that you need to know about `match/case`, as-well-as provide you with alternatives.

[Match/Case Examples and Alternatives](https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/10/python-match-case-statement-example-alternatives.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the match statement from Python 3.10, you can create a switch-like statement with a one line function and use it with a one-pass for loop. It would look very similar to the javascript syntax:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c:v in c

for case in switch(True):

    if case(1 == 1):
        print(1)
        break

    if case( 1 > 1):
        print(2)
        break
else:
    print(3)
```

Note that if you don't use breaks, the conditions will flow through (which would allow multiple cases to be executed if that's what you need).

Answer (score 0):

*Check if you are using Python 3.10, if not then use this instead and*
*also the match case isn't meant to be used liked this, you're better off using switch case if you're just trying to print something out*

The switch case in python is used by creating a function for an 'if-else-if' statement and declaring the case above like:

```
match = int(input("1-3: "))


def switch(case): #Function
    if case == 1:
        print(1)

    elif case > 1:
        print(2)

    else:
        print(3)


switch(match) #Main driver
```

else is the 'default' and you can add as many elif statements.

Comment: No matter how you butter this up, it's just a `def` with conditions in it. +2 virtual points for making it seem like this is a "trick", though. Why would you need python 3.10 for this?